# jQuery asortable: flowing absolutely positioned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs positioning absolutely (it must be) when they sort it overlap to each oders how to fix it, I will add that the absolute position must be.

When i want to replace the largest div from small is small problem.

Please check: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wenbtt7q/

my js file:

```
$('.wrapper').asortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    forceHelperSize: true,
    start: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('start: ');
            console.log(ui);
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('stop: ');
            console.log(ui);
        },
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('create: ');
            console.log(ui);
        },
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('change: ');
            console.log(ui);
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            console.log('receive: ');
            console.log(ui);
        },
        update: function( event, ui ){
            console.log('sort: ');
            console.log(ui);
        },

});
```

my html file:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 150px; left:10px">
            <div class="item-content">
              <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
              This can be anything1.
              <!-- Safe zone ends -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; left:120px">
            <div class="item-content">
              <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
              This can be anythin2.
              <!-- Safe zone ends -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; left:10px; top: 160px">
            <div class="item-content">
              <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
              This can be anything3.
              <!-- Safe zone ends -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

thanks for reply.